# Finding route between 2 points based on same attributes using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, routing

I'm using Arcmap 10.5 and I would like to solve a network analysis problem.

I have a road network layer and two point layers. The first points layer contains the start points, the second one contains the end points (the same count). Both layer has route_id field. I would like to find routes based on this common route_id value. 
So, I would like to find routes from each start point to each end point where the route_id values are the same (overall 100 routes).
They would be very-very simple routes, without any restrictions, barriers etc. Only the shortest paths are needed.

I tried this:

1. I've made a Network Dataset and loaded the road network layer.
2. After that I created a Closest Facility Layer and loaded start points as locations.
3. Next, I loaded end points as Incidents.

I've made routes successfully, but I would like to make routes based on the same attribute values, for example: from the start point with route_id=1 to the end point with route_id=1 etc. with 1 to 1 join.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have one start matching one stop I think you have chosen the wrong sort of analysis, you chose *Closest Facility* I think you need to be using *Route*. This will create a line between start and stop.

So in the example below I loaded stops from start layer and set route name field, I then loaded end stops setting route name field and when you run solve it creates a route for each route name

[image: Output]